# virtual host is not working with WAMP server

Tags: apache, wamp, virtualhost

i have setup WAMP server , it is working fine
Then i tried virtual host with it , it doesn't work

In the httpd.conf file i added these lines

```
Listen 8081
Listen 8082
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

And in the httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 8081 
Listen 8082 

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/docs/dummy-host.localhost"
    ServerName dummy-host.localhost
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost localhost:8081>
    ServerName localhost:8081
    DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www/project/"
    Alias /index.html D:/wamp/www/project/index.php
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost localhost:8082>
    ServerName localhost:8082
    DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www/project1/"
    Alias /index.html D:/wamp/www/project1/index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You only try from the local machine where the server is running on? Because `localhost` is statically associated with `127.0.0.1` (IPv4) and `::1` (IPv6) ;-). So you will run into troubles if you try to access that from another machine.

Comment: What you get error message, when you restart the apache?

Answer (score 3):

I see it's a bit old question but still my WAMP doesn't work with vhost enabled.
hosts:

```
<code>
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 sweetdreams.localhost
127.0.0.1 sweetdreams.com
</code>
```

httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule php5_module "D:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.4/php5apache2_2.dll"
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf


Include "D:/wamp/alias/*"

VirtualDocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www/%0"
```

htppd-vhosts.conf:

```
 NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
   ServerName localhost
   DocumentRoot "d:/wamp/www"                      #this is default wamp root for websites,
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
   ServerName www.sweetdreams.com
   ServerAlias www.sweetdreams.com sweetdreams.com              #your virtual domain name
   DocumentRoot "d:/wamp/www/sweetdreams"                        #location of your site, no extenison needed.

<Directory "d:/wamp/www/sweetdreams">                              #again location of your website
   Order Allow,Deny
   Allow from all
 </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

My WAMP icon stays orange when I enable vhost module and add vhost conf.

Answer (score 2):

i dont understand why you try to point diff ports to diff projects ...

you can write in httpd-vhosts.conf something like this:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www/project/"
    # ServerName project[1 ... n].local or domain.name.com 
    ServerName project1.local
</VirtualHost>
```

then you have to edit your hosts file from C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc in order to match your IP to your local domain

restart apache and that's all

the valid url should be like this: http://project1.local - where you will hve the project1 forlder; 
in order to have multiple projects you can set as many VistualHosts directives you need
cheers,

Answer (score 1):

I was running in to the same issue, When i have the ports in both locatins the server would not run. It would stay at Orange. Try removing the port in the `NameVirtualHost` so it would look like this:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "d:/wamp/www"         
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
ServerName www.sweetdreams.com
ServerAlias www.sweetdreams.com *.sweetdreams.com     
DocumentRoot "d:/wamp/www/sweetdreams"
</VirtualHost>
```