# WAMP Virtual Host not working

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wamp, virtualhost

I am using a wamp version 2.5
My Apache is 2.4.9
PHP: 5.5.12
MySQL: 5.6.17

I have these configurations:

On my `httpd.conf`

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

On my `G:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-vhost.conf`

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.
#


#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "g:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "g:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "g:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "g:\wamp\www\mysite\public"
    ServerName mysite.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

On my `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   mysite.dev
#   ::1     localhost
```

I try to access my project using this URL: `http://www.mysite.dev/` **BUT** I am getting a `Server not found error` I tried accessing it using `www.mysite.dev` , `http://mysite.dev` but still having a bad luck!

My virtual host was working before but i'm not sure why it wasn't working now. Some weird stuff going on.

I am not sure what's happening. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11154840/2518525)?

Comment: In url only use mysite.dev. and check

Comment: And also check in your mysite\public is there index.php?

Comment: @RoshanDandgavhal yes the index.php is there.

Comment: @Darren I will try that one.

Answer (score 21):

First you need to remove the example **dummy** definitions from your vhost-httpd.conf file. They are there as **examples only** just to get you started with the syntax, and should not remain in an active `conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` as they are pointing to non existant folders.

So remove these 2 definitions from the file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "g:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "g:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Second Apache 2.4.x is IPV4 ( 127.0.0.1 ) and IPV6 (::1) aware so your `hosts` file should look like this with definitions for both IPV4 and IPV6 versions for each site. The browser can arbitrarily use either so you need both but will probably use the IPV6 network in preference to the IPV4 if both are actually active on your PC.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1  localhost

127.0.0.1   mysite.dev
::1  mysite.dev
```

Now on the 2 Virtual Hosts that actually exist on your system try this as the Virtual Host definition :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "g:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
    <Directory  "G:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "g:\wamp\www\mysite\public"
    ServerName mysite.dev
    ServerAlias www.mysite.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/mysite-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/mysite-access.log" common
    <Directory  "G:/wamp/www/mysite/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The `<Directory>....</Directory>` section within the `<VirtualHost>....</VirtualHost>` section tells Apache which IP Addresses it is allowed to accept connections from, so using the Apache 2.4 syntax `Require local` limits access so that only the PC running WAMPServer i.e. Apache can connect to any of these site.

Avoid mixing Apache 2.2 syntax and Apache 2.4 syntax together in the same definition. So dont use

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
```

and

```
Require all granted
```

in the same definition. You are using Apache 2.4 so use the Apache 2.4 syntax.

If you find you want to allow other PC's inside your local network to see you site i.e. work mate or the kids etc, you can add this syntax to one or more of your Virtual Host definition.

Allow just a single other PC into your site

```
Require local
Require ip 192.168.1.100
```

or 2 other PC's

```
Require local
Require ip 192.168.1.100, 192.168.1.101
```

Or to anyone on your local network just use the first 3 of the 4 quartiles of the ip address.

```
Require ip 192.168.1
```

Also avoid using the syntax that allows access from anywhere i.e.

```
Require all granted  <--Apache 2.4 syntax

or 

Order Allow,Deny     <-- Apache 2.2 syntax
Allow from all
```

It may solve your issues in the short term, but is just waiting to catch you sometime later when you decide you want to show your site to a friend/client/boss. If you get to the stage of Port Forwarding you router so that the world is allowed into your network that would cause **ALL OF YOUR SITES** to become available to the world.

Better to change the ONE Virtual Host Definition for the ONE site you want people to see for testing/bragging from `Require local` to `Require all granted` and only allow that single site to be access from the internet.

Once you have made all these changes remember to restart Apache.

Also if you change the hosts file to make the chnages active you should either reboot or run these command from the command line of a command windows started ising the `Runs as Administrator` option.

```
net stop dnscache
net start dnscache
```

> If you are using Windows 10  the above dns commands no longer work, you should do this instead.

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Comment: Oh my god I am not sure which one actually worked. ::1 and syntax  difference in versions because I did two changes (IP6 aware hosts file and correcting 2.4 config syntax). I was struggling lot from weeks (which I ended up not using virtual hosts but switch sites when ever needed). Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks a LOT, adding ::1 to my hosts file resolved the problem!

Answer (score 5):

Due to Google acquiring .dev gTLD, having .dev development sites is no longer easily possible, best way to mitigate is to just rename your development domain into .local or something that you prefer.

What happens in the background is that the local DNS server redirects the browser to 127.0.53.53 (open cmd > nslookup yourdomain.dev) in order to inform end-users of .dev gTLD being acquired. Since the .dev domain in hosts file is set to 127.0.0.1 it shows connection refused.

You can change 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.53.53 in the hosts file and see that the browser error changes from ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED to ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION.

Answer (score 2):

Following  is working for me

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "G:\project\test.dev"
    ServerAdmin test@gmail.com
    ServerName test.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/test.dev-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/test.dev-access.log" common
    <Directory "G:\project\test.dev">
       AllowOverride All
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

I fix the same problem by uncomment some lines in httpd.conf in Apache folder.

Uncomment lines below:

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
```

Save file and Restart your Apache and it will work. 
Many thanks to this guy:
https://john-dugan.com/wamp-vhost-setup/

Answer (score 2):

I am coming very late to this question, I did all what was mentioned by @RiggsFolly but one thing I changed made it to work instantly. I changed `.dev` to `.test` as .dev is reserved. hope this helps

Comment: @Jonjie glad it did, i left web dev long ago, but am still useful =D

Comment: haha nice. Anyway, do you know why and where .dev has reserved?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this modules uncommented in httpd.conf

- proxy_module
- proxy_http_module

Answer (score -2):

try this on you apache httpd.config file:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName mysite.dev
      DocumentRoot "g:\wamp\www\mysite\public"
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

     <Directory "g:\wamp\www\mysite\public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options All Includes Indexes
        Options All Indexes FollowSymLinks 
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

restart your wamp server and put url like mysite.dev/ on you browser.
hope it will help you.
thank you.