# issue while creating virtual host in wampserver 3.1.0

Tags: php, localhost, virtualhost, wampserver

Below is the code i putted in **httpd-vhosts.conf** on directory "C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.27\conf\extra"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName customhost.dev
    DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/customhost/"
    <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/customhost/">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

================================================================
Below is the code i putted in host file on directory 
"C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"

::1    localhost

::1    customhost.dev

================================================================
FACING BELOW ISSUE TRIED MANY TIMES!!!
[image]

EVEN IT SHOWING IN FLASH SCREEN OF WAMPSERVER

[image]

Comment: i tried to hit direct this "customhost.dev" in url but same issue.

Comment: ok following you.

Comment: still not working

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47839362/virtual-host-using-wamp-is-not-working - read the part about `.dev` domain name. Your need to choose something else.

Comment: thank you so much  Lawrence Cherone i tried in another browser and its working problem is .dev it reserved for something we have to choose something else thank you again.

Comment: Yeah ill have to remember this one too, imo icann should of not allowed it, what next `.local`..